# I need this code with dynamicly

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, case

I have a header menu and i do not want to add for each menu link in switch case like this, how can i do it dynamic...

```
var sections = $(".href a");
var content = $("#load");

sections.click(function(){
    switch(this.id){            
        case ('/p/settings/header-settings'):
            $(content).load('/p/settings/header-settings #load');
            window.history.pushState('user', 'user', '/p/settings/header-settings');
            break;
        case ('/p/settings/site-verifications'):
            $(content).load('/p/settings/site-verifications #load');
            window.history.pushState('user', 'user', '/p/settings/site-verifications');
            break;
        case ('/p/settings/analysis-settings'):
            $(content).load('/p/settings/analysis-settings #load');
            window.history.pushState('user', 'user', '/p/settings/header-settings');
            break;
        default:
            $(content).load('/p #load' );
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you have a specific set of options to allow? Or should an allowable option fall into some pattern, say `/p/settings/*` or... other?

Comment: dont have any specific set options to allow...

Comment: Then how do you decide what falls into the default case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly pass the id with respected place instead of switch .And do with `on()` for dynamically append element .Its will perform depend on your id

```js
var sections = $(".href a");
var content = $("#load");

sections.on('click', function() {
  var id = this.id;
  if(condition) //add with some  false condition as you wish for go to  default statement s
 {
  $(content).load('/p #load' );
 }else{
  $(content).load(id + ' #load');
  window.history.pushState('user', 'user', id);
  }
});
```

Comment: How it will dead with the *default*  option?

Comment: what if `id` is defined but not in the case you can't say the `id` to be undefined for the default case

Comment: @NadirLaskar i just `!` add for false statement define.not focus mainly as `id` undefined

Comment: what if the id is not falsely for section that needs to be sent to default.

Comment: @NadirLaskar its not a switch case for applying default statement .And also i m not mention only the `id` .need some condition for seperate default case  and other case

Answer (score 0):

Use this JS instead of your switch case. if you don't worry about default case

```
sections.click(function(){

    $(content).load(this.id+' #load');
    window.history.pushState('user', 'user', this.id);

});
```

If you want to take care of default condition too then you can use simplified switch case as shown below.

```
sections.click(function(){
    switch(this.id){            
        case ('/p/settings/header-settings'):
        case ('/p/settings/site-verifications'):
        case ('/p/settings/analysis-settings'):

        //For more case just add here the below code remain same

        $(content).load(this.id+' #load');
        window.history.pushState('user', 'user', this.id);

        break;
        default:
            $(content).load('/p #load' );
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks so much, now i have a problem too.  $('#tabs').tabs(); jquery tabs not working when it is load...